# Overfitting in data frame that some rows repeated

Tags: machine-learning, logistic-regression, supervised-learning, overfitting-underfitting

I have a machine learning problem in a logistic regression algorithm. That I have a data frame where some rows and features are repeated like the below table:

| feature 1 | feature 2 | feature 3 | ... | feature n-1 | feature n | Target |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| a1 | a2 | a3 | .. | an | 1 | 1 |
| b1 | b2 | b3 | .. | bn | 1 | 0 |
| c1 | c2 | c3 | .. | cn | 1 | 1 |
| .. | .. | .. | .. | .. | 1 | .. |
| a1 | a2 | a3 | .. | an | 2 | .. |
| b1 | b2 | b3 | .. | bn | 2 | .. |
| c1 | c2 | c3 | .. | cn | 2 | .. |
| .. | .. | .. | .. | .. | 2 | .. |
| a1 | a2 | a3 | .. | an | 3 | .. |
| b1 | b2 | b3 | .. | bn | 3 | .. |
| c1 | c2 | c3 | .. | cn | 3 | .. |
| .. | .. | .. | .. | .. | .. | .. |

Is it possible to occur overfitting or underfitting with this data frame or not?

And what about a data frame that has between 6 or 8 features with about 500 rows?

I should add and notice this, rows that are repeated in features from 1 to n-1 vary in feature n.

Comment: They are identical across samples except for the last feature which is probably the label (target) so they are not informative at all. Why don't you [drop](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.drop_duplicates.html) the duplicates before model fitting?

Comment: @seralouk
The last feature is not target (feature n is not target).

Comment: This is not a *programming* question, please see the intro and NOTE in https://stackoverflow.com/tags/machine-learning/info.

Comment: And if `feature-n` is not a label, then the rows are not identical...

Comment: yes they vary in feature n 
@desertnaut

Comment: @PooryaAlishahKamandi ok you edited your post after my answer. Regardless, for the "almost identical" rows, only the feature n brings some information. This is not a problem per se.

Answer (score 0):

Whether you overfit or not is due to:

- the complexity of the model
- the available data.

But what's important is the *actual* data. If you double the data by repeating it, you don't effectively change the data you have. In fact, many algorithms randomly sample from the dataset. So, having duplicates changes nothing (except if the duplicated data has a different distribution than the non-duplicated data)

As such, removing the duplication in the data will not affect whether your overfit or not.

**Edit:** Now, if the data is not *duplicated*, but rather *modified*, it is a different story:

> where some rows and features are repeated

Then, no effect.

But if the data is *modified*, as the table shows, then you need to explain: Is this actual noisy measurements? Is this some random transcription/data collection error?

**However, if it is not errors in the dataset but actual data, then it is important to keep it.** This is not about overfitting, this is about training with the actual data.

Comment: so you mean changing the last feature has no effect on my model accuracy ?? 
@jeffrey

Comment: see edit. I missed that what you stated and what the data shows was different

Comment: I should add and notice this, data that is repeated in features from 1 to n-1 vary in feature n.  @Jeffrey